# How do you analyse the traffic of a website from the outside?

Tags: traffic

I am looking to scrape a website which contains useful public data, but they do not provide an API. I would like to publish this data in a more useful format.

Out of respect for the organisation, I want to run the daily scrape at a time when the site is experiencing low traffic. How can I find out when the site is being used least without being a member of staff at the organisation that runs it?

I am guessing that I should just run the scrape rate limited at 2am and hope for the best, however is there a more accurate method?

Answer (score 2):

Reviewing traffic information requires access to the Webalizer/AWstats (or similar) metrics, which as an outsider you won't have access to.

Scraping will only allow you to take a copy of the website for offline view/archiving purposes, and we already have sites that do this like waybackmachine.com

Comment: Thought as much. I do appreciate that scaping just gets me the data, not the site traffic. Thanks!